# in python is there a better way to apply a list of functions to a dictionary

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

Is there a better way to *iteratively* apply a list of functions to a dictionary? Here is an example of what I want to do.  But this uses recursion.

```
def func1(h: dict):
    h['foo']=10
    return(h)

def func2(h: dict):
    h['bar']=100
    return(h)

def func3(h: dict):
    h['baz']=h['foo']+h['bar']
    return(h)

func3(func2(func1({'firstElement':'good'})))
```

Produces expected output:

```
{'bar': 100, 'baz': 110, 'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10}
```

I want to provide the functions as a array and produce the same output.  Here is what I have tried and works:

```
def recApply(flist, h=None):
    """
    Helper Apply the list of functions iteratively over the dictionary passed
    :obj: function list each will be applied to the dictionary sequentially.
    """
    #if no dictionary passed, then set the dictionary.
    if(h == None):
        h = {}

    #iteratively call functions with dictionary as a passed parameter and returning a derived dictionary
    for f in flist:
        h = f(h)

    return(h)

flist = [func1,func2,func3]
recApply(flist,{'firstElement':'good'})
```

This produces the desired output:

```
{'bar': 100, 'baz': 110, 'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10}
```

Is there a way to do this that is more readable, removes the recApply function and hopefully minimizes dictionary copies?

Comment: This doesn't copy any dictionaries; a reference to the same mutated dictionary is passed into and back from each function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to return your dictionaries and re-assign references - mutable types are passed by reference so:

```
def func1(h):
    h['foo'] = 10

def func2(h):
    h['bar'] = 100

def func3(h):
    h['baz'] = h['foo'] + h['bar']

start_dict = {'firstElement': 'good'}

for f in (func1, func2, func3):
    f(start_dict)

print(start_dict)
# {'firstElement': 'good', 'baz': 110, 'bar': 100, 'foo': 10}
```

would to perfectly fine.

Comment: All arguments in Python are passed in the same way https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @chthonicdaemon - true, but we're talking about semantics here. You always pass a reference to a value, but only mutable types can be changed producing the 'pass-by-reference' vs 'pass-by-value' distinction (that exists in most languages) in practice.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` (or `functools.reduce` in Python 3) can be used to compose a list of functions into a single function. This requires you to define a composition function:

```
def compose(f, g):
    def _(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return _
```

and an identity function:

```
def identity(x):
    return x
```

Using these, you can create a function `g` that applies each function in order to an initial input.

```
g = reduce(compose, [func3, func2, func1], identity)
assert (g({'firstElement': 'good'}) ==
        {'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10, 'bar': 100, 'baz': 110})
```

---

Note this works because `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are similar enough to pure functions that you can make use of the function [*monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Loosely speaking, it just means that function composition is associative (`compose(f, compose(g, h))` is the same as `compose(compose(f, g), h)`) and that the identity function is neutral under composition (`compose(identity, f)` and `compose(f, identity)` are both the same as `f` itself).

Your three functions aren't really pure functions; they are more like identity functions with side effects. However, you can treat them as pure functions because you are using them as if they were defined as, for example,

```
def func1(h):
    h1 = {}
    h1.update(h)
    h1['foo'] = 10
    return h1
```

---

Exercise for the reader: determine if my call to `reduce` actually defines `g(x) = func3(func2(func1(x)))` or `g(x) = func1(func2(func3(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python 3) with the starting dictionary as the `initializer` parameter:

```
>>> from functools import reduce  # Python 3
>>> reduce(lambda (x, f): f(x), (func1, func2, func3), {'firstElement':'good'})
{'bar': 100, 'baz': 110, 'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10}
```

This will apply the functions one after the other to the initializer or the result of the previous function.

You could also combine this with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a chained function that can then be applied to different input dictionaries:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> chain = partial(reduce, lambda (x, f): f(x), (func1, func2, func3))
>>> chain({'firstElement':'good'})
{'bar': 100, 'baz': 110, 'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10}
```

And you could generalize that further, making it a `partial` of a `partial` function...

```
>>> chainer = partial(partial, reduce, lambda (x, f): f(x))
>>> chain = chainer((func1, func2, func3))
>>> chain({'firstElement':'good'})
{'bar': 100, 'baz': 110, 'firstElement': 'good', 'foo': 10}
```